# is it possible to add menu items to woo commerce my accounts page on plugin activation?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a custom plugin using WordPress Plugin Boilerplate Generator . Is it possible to create new menu items in woo commerce my accounts page when the plugin is activated ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's rather long to put it here. I'd rather provide you a link to a tutorial, ([Customising account page tabs](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Customising-account-page-tabs)), from WooCommerce github.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure its possible. First you need to register a new endpoint in WordPress using the add_rewrite_endpoint() function and also register it via the query_vars filter.

I did that similar stuff on a site named xduit.com around 2 years back.